# Postgres SQL - At least one row is selected from in clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, common-table-expression

I have a table with the following structure

```
 ID,Content,QuestionMarks,TypeofQuestion,difficulty

 350, What is the symbol used to represent Bromine?,2,MCQ,Easy
 758,What is the symbol used to represent Bromine? ,2,MCQ,Easy
 2425,What is the symbol used to represent Bromine?,3,Essay,Intermediate
 2080,A quadrilateral has four sides, four angles  ,1,MCQ,Easy
 2614,A circular cone has a curved surface area of ,2,MCQ,Easy
 2520,Two triangles have sides 5 cm, 11 cm, 2 cm . ,2,MCQ,Advanced
 2196,Life supporting process mediated by water?   ,2,Essay,Intermediate
```

I am using the SQL below to get random questions where total marks is an input number. For example if I say 25, the result should be all the random questions whose Sum(QuestionMarks) is 25(+/-1)

```
with q25 as (
      select *
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(questionmark) over (order by random()) as running_questionmark
            from t
           ) t
      where running_questionmark < 25
     )
select q.ID, q.Content, q.QuestionMarks, q.TypeofQuestion
from q25 q
union all
(select t.ID, t.Content, t.QuestionMarks, t.TypeofQuestion
 from t cross join
        (select sum(questionmark) as questionmark_25 from q25) x
 where not exists (select 1 from q25 where q25.id = t.id) 
 order by abs(questionmark - (25 - questionmark_25))
 limit 1
)
```

**Expected Result:**
I want to ensure atleast 2 Essay Type question is always selected if it exists.
Also, the result should be a mix of all the difficulty levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In q25 select two essay questions *first* then the rest.  A pretty simple way is to peg the "random" value to "2" for two essay questions.  Do note that you might get additional essay questions -- but your question says "at least 2":

```
with q25 as (
      select *
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(questionmark) over (order by rnd) as running_questionmark
            from (select t.*,
                         (case when TypeofQuestion = 'Essay' and
                                    row_number() over (partition by TypeofQuestion order by random()) <= 2
                               then -1.0
                               else random()
                          end) as rnd
                  from t
                 ) t
           ) t
      where running_questionmark < 25
     )
select q.ID, q.Content, q.QuestionMarks, q.TypeofQuestion
from q25 q
union all
(select t.ID, t.Content, t.QuestionMarks, t.TypeofQuestion
 from t cross join
        (select sum(questionmark) as questionmark_25 from q25) x
 where not exists (select 1 from q25 where q25.id = t.id) 
 order by abs(questionmark - (25 - questionmark_25))
 limit 1
)
```